# Reading remote PDF files with JavaScript

Tags: javascript, ios, pdf, cordova

I'm working on an iphone app, that would read pdf files from the folder on web server.
I made the part of app which read PDF files and everthing is fine, now i'm trying to figure out how to load all pdf files from http:/www.blabla.com/pdf, so everytime i upload new pdf, the app would automaticly load it.

Is this possibile, and anybody has ideas how can be done?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can only be done, by either having Directory Index enabled, or using a server side language such as PHP to read the contents of that folder and output the filenames.

Comment: I think using PHP is better solution. Thanks man, this will not be easy as i tought.

Comment: PHP is simple ;) http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.scandir.php will simply spit out an array of files/folders in a given folder. You can then use `json_encode` to convert that to JSON, use Ajax to get the information and go from there ;) Simples...

Comment: Hahaha, i know php, and some javascripting, but json, ajax... what? :D Can i simply create an array of files and read it with javascript?

Comment: If your using PHP to render the initial page then yes, this can be done. If you are wanting to get the list, after the page has loaded, you would need to look into Ajax.

Comment: Oook man, thanks for answers! This got me in right direction to work on!

Comment: One question, i've created an array of files using json_encode, now using jQuery.getJSON(), as url can i enter the url of php file with the array or something else is?

Comment: Yup, you just need to use $.ajax/get/post/getJSON and point it to the URL that outputs the file list in JSON format. From there, you can use javascript to read the JSON as an array again, allowing you to create a loop etc.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/14185/discussion-between-gavin-and-bojan-vidanovic)

Comment: Edit: The above assumes that you are trying to get the list of pdf's AFTER the page has loaded. If you are doing it before and are serving a PHP page, you can simply output the list of PDFs directly to the browser.